# Test SNMP traps on SolarWinds by sending trap from a CentOS box

Tags: linux, snmp, monitoring

How can I generate a test trap with a CentOS box to send to a remote monitoring box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `snmptrap` - see http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptrap.html for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Restart the snmpd service, `service snmpd restart`. That should send agent shutdown/start traps.